# При подключении БД ошибка: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, nextjs

Было изначально решено, что будет отдельно приложение на NextJS и на Node.js бэкенд. Но потом решил, что могу API закинуть в pages и оттуда брать данные.

Так вот, проблема сейчас в том, что я не могу вынести данные с БД на сервер:

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '',
    user: '',
    password: '',
    database: ''
})

exports.query = async(query) => {
    try {
        const results = await connection.query(query)
        await connection.end()
        return results
    }
    catch(error) {
        return { error }
    }
}
```

Ну и потом в api/posts/index.js:

```
import db from '../controllers/database'

module.exports = async(request, response) => {
    const sql = `select * from post`
    const posts = await db.query(sql)

    response.status(200).json({
        posts
    })
}
```

Хочу вывести данные, но получаю ошибку:

> Converting circular structure to JSON...

Ну а до этого, все было хорошо (когда делал нодовскую маршрутизацию):

```
router.get('/', (request, response) => {
    const sql = `select * from post`

    database.query(sql, (error, data, fields) => {
        if(error) throw error

        response.json({
            status: 200,
            data,
            message: 'Posts lists are retvieved successfully'
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> const mysql = require('mysql')
>
> ...
>
> const results = await connection.query(query)

Судя по документации, библиотека `mysql` не умеет работать с promise, только с callback функциями. Так что, при отдаче ответа вы пытаетесь сериализовать непонятно что.

Comment: Спасибо что натолкнули на решение!

Comment: я слышал, обычно используют библиотеку mysql2, она с промисами. а next, скорее всего, typeorm использует

Answer (score 1):

Пользователь [@nörbörnën](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1191940), был прав - `mysql` не поддерживает работу с промисами. Для этого нужно переписать как в документации через калбэки.

Но, я решил использовать `serverless-mysql`:

```
const mysql = require('serverless-mysql')

const connection = mysql({
    config: {
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'pass',
        database: 'dbname'
    }
})
```